# Unable to locate package php

Tags: php, installation

I'm installing a LAMP stack on an Ubuntu instance in Google Compute Engine. I'm following the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp 
where I'm instructed to enter 
sudo apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php

When I press Enter, I get this message: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php

Apparently Apache was installed because I can browse the page, but php and libapache2-mod-php are not found. Have the names been changed for these packages?

Comment: Chances are you need `php5` or `php7.x` packages. Since PHP 7 came out I believe Ubuntu has started differentiating between the various versions.

Answer (score 4):

The ubuntu package is called php7.0

```
apt-get install php7.0
```

You may also want to use

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

In the future, you can check https://packages.ubuntu.com or run

```
apt-cache search php
```

Answer (score 2):

Packages names can diverge with ubuntu version.
You can locate php packages names with a search command:

```
apt-cache search php
```

Be sure have an updated packages list before :

```
apt-get update
```